# Botframework vs. Roll Your Own

Tags: botframework

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I have no experience using botframework or Azure AI, so perhaps my question is completely ignorant.  I want to create a chabot that will take inbound appointment requests and offer up possible options in response.  I briefly reviewed some of the documentation and it appears you must set up certain trigger phrases that will cause a response.  So if this is the case, I'm trying to understand what benefits the bot framework provides assuming the purpose of the chatbot is fairly narrow in scope and NLP is not at a premium.  Obviously, after the purpose of the inbound request is determined, most of the response must come from our database and business logic.  So I'm not completely following how the botframework aids this application.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after the purpose of the inbound request is determined, most of the response must come from our database and business logic. So I'm not completely following how the botframework aids this application.

If you just want to build a chat application that can receive messages from user, understand the user’s intent, retrieve from database and generate respond accordingly, the Microsoft Bot Framework is not only one approach/way to achieve the requirement. But the Microsoft Bot Framework would provide these benefits:

- BotBuilder SDKs and template (including basic, form, language
  understanding, question and answer, and proactive bots) can speeds up
  development.
- The bot can naturally interact with your users on a website, app,
  Cortana, Microsoft Teams, Skype, Slack, Facebook Messenger, and more.
- Easily integrate with another Azure services, such as Azure storage
  etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Please bear with me if my questions are ignorant as I am just trying to learn.  Let's assume I am not using any other Azure services and the servers is conventionally hosted.  So let's assume I want a chabot to check on the availability of appointments.  So the way I see this application working is the chatbot would need to determine if the text asks for an appointment.  Is this where the SDK's and templates come into play as opposed to using something like regex to look for keywords?

Comment: `the way I see this application working is the chatbot would need to determine if the text asks for an appointment.` To detect/recognize user's intent, you can use [LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-get-started-cs-get-intent) etc language understanding API services. Besides, if you are web developer, to build real-time chat application, you can use WebSocket technology or [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my reasons for doing an Azure Bot Service:

- Using the Bot Framework offers up the whole Azure infrastructure e.g. database, LUIS, cognitive services, Machine Learning, etc.
- If you decide to look into Machine Learning, you can develop a web service to return learned results rather than coding lots of if..else if..then.
- On top of this, you are able to integrate with various channels such as Facebook, Slack, Skype or straight up on a website.
- An added benefit is that you can also make use of Azure's auto-scaling features, depending on the traffic you expect.
- You also have the ability to customize the code as it is simply a .NET project.

If you're a developer like me, you love debugging through your code. If you're interested, I've written up [an article to explain how to debug a bot service](https://www.developerlabs.co/articles/2018/3/18/debug-your-bot-service) on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You say that what the framework provides seems a bit narrow, but I see it as exactly simplifying that part of detecting what the user wants to do. I wouldn't say that the bot framework logic is trivial, but it makes it seem trivial so that you can focus on your business logic.
Think of it as a new user interface, maybe you already have a system to make appointments. Now you add the bot to handle the flow for a new interface which is chat based.

It is not trivial, it will help you identify the user intents. Use it for that, then you can handle your other logic outside of the bot. It doesn't need to handle your whole app logic to be useful or good.